# How can I save the result of a Stack Exchange API call into a text file using curl?

Tags: support, api

As I run the following,

```bash
curl https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-on-users#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=912523&filter=default&site=math&run=true > result.txt
```

[image]

I got the above at end of the terminal, and as I press enter key,

[image]

The statement with "Done" is represented and the command finishes processing.

I expect the result is inside `result.txt` however actually it not.

Can anyone give me some wisdom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're *not* calling the API; you're calling the *documentation* page. You need to use the link indicated below:

[image]

and use the `--compressed` option (see [Decompressing API Responses](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression) for why this is necessary):

```
curl "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.3/users/912523/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=math" --compressed > result.txt
```